# Java Reading from stdin

Tags: java, io, lexer, reader

I have a lexer that accepts Reader object. Initially it is intended to parse files, but
I want to run lexer with stdin to make a repl

so, here is my code

```java
private static void launchRepl() {
        final var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("> ");
            var lexer = new Lexer(reader);
            while (true) {
                var token = lexer.readToken();
                var ttype = token.tokenType();
                if (ttype == TokenType.Eof || ttype == TokenType.StatementEnd) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(token);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the language i tokenize, new line is of TokenType.StatementEnd. But when I write new input to the console and hit enter, my lexer does not see this new line character and blocks, until i press enter one more time. So it works like:

> > 1 + 2 
> Number 1 
> Operator + 
> Number 2 
> (waiting for another enter) **hits enter** 
> >

I want to fix so it sees \n at the end of the prompt

Comment: So I did a really quick test which just used `br.readLine` in a `while-loop` which basically echoed what I wrote.  What I noticed was, `readLine` was not returning the new line character.  So, I had a quick look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and it states *"A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached without reading any characters"* which matches what I was seeing.  Obviously, this is guess work

Comment: So, I did another test using `read` and what I found was, for me at least, the new line character `\n` was (int) `10` - again, lots of "assumptions" and "guess work", as we don't know how your `Lexer` actually works

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is interesting. So, do you think that CR (ASCII 13) is being ignored as well? It can't be. Otherwise, how it is returning back to character column 0?

Comment: I don't think `CR/13` is been ignored, I don't think the console is generating it.  Dump each character you read from the `Reader` and see what you're getting.  You might find using a `Scanner` might be more pratical over all

Comment: @MadProgrammer `'\n' == (char) 10`. In most (all) programming languages.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thank you I'm (vaguely) aware, but the OP needs to be made more aware.  I don't tend to do this kind of "low level" reading of console input (use a `Scanner` because I'm lazy) or just something like `BufferedReader#readLine` which solves more the issues

Comment: I have a hunch that `"1 + 2\n + 3"` could be tokenized. So how should the toknenizer know that you want a new line to mean "end of input"?